# SQL Server sum query every 06:30 AM

Tags: sql-server

Really need some help: I have a SQL Server table like this :

[image]

And I want to do a query to count value everyday start from 06:30 today until 06:29 tomorrow.

The problem is, the value does not start from 0 every 06:30.

I need query like this: Select maximum value per code first, ex :

```
(code : value)
M12 : 108, 
M77 : 26
```

then the M77 value not start from 06:30.

I need to do : 26 - 12 (value before 06:30:00), so the M77 now is 14.

Finally sum the M77 and M12 = 14 + 108 = 122.

My expected output only for total value per date.

Based on my DB (image), the total value will be 26 - 12 =14.

- 26 is the latest value.
- 12 is value before 06:30

How to do it in SQL Server? Please help me

Comment: Do you need to sum by _code_ or do you need to sum by _time_?  Your question does not make this entirely clear.

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: I've updated the expected output.
I need to count the value 06:30 today until 06:29 tomorrow in all code. please help me..

Comment: This isn't the update we really want to see.  Please show a _table_, formatted as _text_, with the expected output.  Then, it will be easy for someone to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

if i do understand you requirement correctly.

The query explanation are in code comments

```
; with 
-- for getting the max value by code, rn = 1 is the max value
cte1 as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by code order by value desc)
    from    sample_table
),
-- for getting rows before 6:30, rn = 1 is the last record before 6:30
cte2 as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by code order by [date] desc)
    from    sample_table
    where   convert(time, [date])   < '06:30'
)
select  total = sum(case when convert(time, c1.[date]) < '06:30' 
                         then c1.value 
                         else c1.value - c2.value 
                         end)
from    cte1 c1
        left join cte2 c2   on  c1.code     = c2.code
                           and  c1.rn       = c2.rn
where   c1.rn   = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM([output]) AS [output]
FROM (
    SELECT [latest]
          ,[before]
          ,(CASE WHEN [latest] = [before] THEN [latest]
           ELSE [latest] - [before] END) AS [output]
    FROM (
    SELECT  [code]
           ,MAX([value]) AS [latest]
           ,(SELECT MAX([value])
             FROM [table]
             WHERE [date] < CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, [date])) + ' 06:30:00:000')
             AND [code] = [t].[code]
             GROUP BY [code]) AS [before]
    FROM [table] AS [t]
    GROUP BY [code]) AS [src]
) AS [rpt]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
but still not in my expectation.

In your query, we got all the maximum value from each code and sum it.

We want to, if value from one code doesn't start from 0 at 06:30, then we need to do max value - value at 06:30 first to get the real data about value start from 06:30 for those code.

Comment: Show your expected output because the way you explain it in sentence is hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this puzzle:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
[date]  datetime,
value   int,
code    varchar(10)
)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
       ([date]
       ,[value]
       ,[code])
 VALUES
    ('2018-09-13 06:20:52.803'   
               ,100
               ,'M12'),
    ('2018-09-13 06:21:52.803'   
       ,102
       ,'M12')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:22:52.803'    
               ,104
               ,'M12')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:23:52.803'    
               ,106
               ,'M12')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:24:52.803'    
               ,108
               ,'M12')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:25:52.803'    
               ,2
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:29:14.803'    
               ,4
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:29:16.803'    
               ,6
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:29:18.803'    
               ,8
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:29:45.803'    
               ,10
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:29:55.803'    
               ,12
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:30:18.803'    
               ,14
               ,'M77')
    ,  ('2018-09-13 06:31:18.803'    
               ,26
               ,'M77')

;WITH RESULT AS (
SELECT 
  TT.code   
, MaxValueThatday          = max(maxval.MAXVALUE )              
, MaxValueBefore630NextDay = max(MAXValBefore630.MAXVALUE)
, ResultSubstraction = 
 CASE WHEN max(maxval.MAXVALUE ) <>  max(MAXValBefore630.MAXVALUE)
        THEN max(maxval.MAXVALUE )  - max(MAXValBefore630.MAXVALUE)
    ELSE max(maxval.MAXVALUE ) 
END
FROM  [dbo].[TestTable] TT
 OUTER APPLY(   
            SELECT max(VALUE) MAXVALUE
                , code 
             FROM [dbo].[TestTable] aa
                WHERE Aa.code = tt.code
            group by code
        )maxval
 OUTER APPLY(   
            SELECT max(A.VALUE) MAXVALUE
                , code
             FROM [dbo].[TestTable] A
                 WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,[DATE]) <= 6 AND DATEPART(MINUTE,[DATE]) < 30 
                 and A.code = tt.code
            group by code
        )MAXValBefore630
where    ( [DATE] > DATEADD(MINUTE,390,CAST({ fn CURDATE()} AS DATETIME) ) ) --6:30 today
group by tt.code

)
SELECT SUM(ResultSubstraction)
 FROM RESULT
```

Comment: BINGO!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! So how to use the query in my C# code? just copy paste the string? Because I want to display the result in web browser

Comment: Could you please post how are you calling through C#?

Comment: I failed to use your query's suggestion in C#. Would you please teach me how to place it ?

Comment: Did you copy only the part after ;With CTE correct?

Comment: Yes I tried to copy code after :With and tried to paste it into c#. Please teach me..

Comment: Yes, you can. Let take a look into it. Could you please motivate me with few Stack points? :). Email me to geraldo.diaz@outlook.com

Comment: Diaz, please open this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809103/sql-server-query-to-count-value-every-0630